# Perl match multiline string and replace

Tags: perl

I have a file located in a remote host.I want to replace a string `cronExpression value="* 30 9 ? * MON-FRI"` to `cronExpression value="* $hour $min ? * MON-FRI"` in that file.

Input file is: `test.properties`

Its contents are like:

```
<bean id="DisconnectCronTrigger"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="delayDisconnectJobDetail" />
<property name="cronExpression" value="* 30 20 ? * MON-FRI" />
</bean>
<bean id="retryJobDetail"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
<property name="targetObject" ref="retryMeterCommandJob" />
<property name="targetMethod" value="executeAll" />
</bean>
<bean id="retryCronTrigger"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="retryJobDetail" />
<property name="cronExpression" value="* 30 9 ? * MON-FRI" />
</bean>
```

I tried the below mentioned code but failed to replace

```
%opts =(user => 'xxxxx',
password => '1234444');
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("$host", %opts);
$ssh->error and die "Can't ssh to $host: " . $ssh->error;

$pathFolder="perl -pi -e  'sm/\<property name=\"jobDetail\"    ref=\"delayDisconnectJobDetail\" \/\>.*?
            \<property name=\"cronExpression\" value=\"\* 30 20 \? \* MON\-FRI\" /\<property name=\"jobDetail\"    ref=\"delayDisconnectJobDetail\" \/\>.*?
            \<property name=\"cronExpression\" value=\"\* **40 10** \? \* MON\-FRI\"/gsm'     /test.properties";
$ssh->system("$pathFolder") or     die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;

<property name="targetMethod" value="executeAll" />
</bean>
<bean id="retryCronTrigger"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
<property name="jobDetail" ref="retryJobDetail" />
<property name="cronExpression" value="* 30 9 ? * MON-FRI" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `sm///` in Perl. The [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) is `s///` and the [match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) is `m//`. Probably that gave you a syntax error. Also doing this through the command line when you already have a Perl is a bit strange.

You can savely use an XML parser, even if it is not installed in the remote host. Take a look at [Object::Remote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Remote), which lets you run Perl code and even use Perl modules from your local machine on a remote machine through SSH. [The author mst talks about that in *the __END__ of everything*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hIyawUrCcQ&index=37&list=PLiKOSMurci-jUdnXdTGCWHzONJitWpb0z).

Answer (score 2):

You can let Net::OpenSSH do the shell quoting for you and get rid of one of your problems. Though, in any case, using regular expressions to handle XML is usually a bad idea as any minor change in the XML file could break your script.

As it seems your files are not too big, just copy then to the local machine using `scp`, do any required processing locally using a proper XML handling module as [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) and finally copy them back to the remote machine:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
use XML::LibXML;

my $hour = '...';
my $min = '...';

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
                            user => 'xxxxx',
                            password => '1234444');
$ssh->error and die "Can't ssh to $host: " . $ssh->error;

$ssh->system(cp => '/test.properties', '/test.properties.bak'); # backup
$ssh->scp_get("/test.properties");

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'test.properties');
for my $ele ($dom->findnodes('/config/bean[property[@name="jobDetail" and
                                            @ref="delayDisconnectJobDetail"]]
                                          /property[@name="cronExpression"]')) {
    $ele->setAttribute(value => "* $hour $min ? * MON-FRI");
}

open my $out, '>', 'test.properties.new';
binmode $out;
$dom->toFH($out);

$ssh->scp_put('test.properties.new', '/test.properties');
```